# Expand flat object into hierarchical structure

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find best approach to expand this flat structure

```
var input = [  
   {  
      "path":"/",
      "size":1111
   },
    {  
      "path":"/test1",
      "size":2222
   },
   {  
      "path":"/test1/folder2",
      "size":3333
   },
   {  
      "path":"/test1/folder2",
      "size":4444
   },
   {  
      "path":"/test7/folder1",
      "size":5555
   }
]
```

into this hierarchical structure

```
var expectedoutput = [{
    "path": "/",
    "size": 1111
  },
  {
    "path": "/test1",
    "size": 2222,
    "items": [{
        "path": "/test1/folder2",
        "size": 3333,
      },
      {
        "path": "/test1/folder2",
        "size": 4444
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "path": "/test7",
    "items": [{
      "path": "/test7/folder1",
      "size": 5555
    }]
  }
]
```

Any ideas? please.

Comment: you could add your *no so bad approach* ...

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far. Do not ask people to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so bad approach, it work's  <strike>but there is one scenario which it cannot handle
Scenario when parent node doesn't exists (should be created) i've commented this part.</strike>

Updated version with missing intermediate paths support

```
function expand_object(list) {
    var map = {}, node, roots = [], i;
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        map[list[i].path] = i; // map  
        list[i].items = []; // place for children
    }
    for (i = 0; i < list.length; i += 1) {
        node = list[i];

        //find parent, example  "path":"test1/folder2"  parent= "test1"
        var lastSlash = node.path.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (lastSlash > 1) {
            lastSlash = lastSlash == -1 ? node.path.length : lastSlash;
            parentNode = node.path.substring(0, lastSlash);
        }
        else {
            parentNode = "/";
        }

        if (parentNode !== "/") {
            // creat missing nodes
            if (!list[map[parentNode]]) {

                list.push({ "name": parentNode ,"path": parentNode, "items": [] })
                map[list[list.length-1].path] = list.length-1;
            }

            var c = list[map[parentNode]];
            list[map[parentNode]].items.push(node);


        } else {
            roots.push(node);
        }
    }
    return roots;
}
var input = [  
   {  
      "path":"/",
      "size":1111
   },
      {  
      "path":"/",
      "size":2222
   },
    {  
      "path":"/test1",
      "size":2222
   },
   {  
      "path":"/test1/folder2",
      "size":3333
   },
   {  
      "path":"/test1/folder2",
      "size":4444
   }

 ,
    { //Missing node
       "path":"/test7/folder1",
       "size":5555
    }
]
console.log(expand_object(input));
```